# remove a sub set from set in Clingo

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

I am new to Clingo and encountered a situation where I needed to remove a subset from the answer set. For example, I have `p(1..9).` and I want to remove `p(5)` from my answer set. How can I do it? Without creating a new answer set? Consider that I have just one answer set as result and if I remove it with `:- p(5).` the program will result in unsatisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an answer set with `p(5)` in it, and proceed to rule out `p(5)` as a possibility with `:- p(5)`, and the solver then reports the problem as unsatisfiable, then with your given inputs there are simply no answer sets that exist that `p(5)` isn't a part of.